# Why does `to_json` on DataMapper objects and collections cause infinite queries?

Tags: ruby, json, serialization, datamapper

I'm using DataMapper in a Rails project, and have found that calling `to_json` on either a model instance or collection results in weird behavior: either a circular reference error from JSON, or **an infinite series of the same query**.

Assuming this was a problem with my model definitions, I opened a Rails console and created the simplest possible model:

```
class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
end

Foo.auto_migrate!  # create db table `foos` for this model
```

After saving an instance of this model, I did this:

```
f = Foo.first
f.to_json
```

At this point, the process appears to hang. If I `tail -f log/development.log`, I see this query executing over and over:

```
SQL (0.084ms)  SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `foos` ORDER BY `id`
```

Ruby's memory usage continues to grow until I interrupt the command or kill the Ruby process. This is the same problem I had with my actual models, so I don't think it was related to a wrong model definition.

What causes this bizarre behavior?

Comment: Although I don't know why this happens, the dm-serializer gem gives me working `to_json` behavior: https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer. I wanted to at least put this problem on the web for others to find this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the Object#to_json method, as implemented by ActiveSupport, serializes all the attributes of the object. Datamapper maintains a self-referential variable (@_repository) that sends the method into a recursive tailspin.

Good news is that the dm-serializer gem (as you mentioned) provides the necessary functionality, and the Rails has already stated how to [fix the problem in the dm-rails project](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4547-activesupport-to_json-doesnt-work-with-dm) (it just hasn't happened yet).